# SVG works locally, but not on remote server wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, advanced-custom-fields

This gives migraine. I just finished my website locally and moved it to my server. Now I've setup the theme with enabled SVG plugin locally and it worked like a charm. On my external server it does not (www.mantasmilka.com  > single post is the one I am working on.

```
<?php
        // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('info_tools') ):
       ?>
        <div class="icon-holder">
          <?php
           // loop through the rows of data
             while ( have_rows('info_tools') ) : the_row();
                // vars
                $tool_image = get_sub_field('image');
                $tool_name = get_sub_field('name');
          ?>
          <a href="#" class="<?php echo $tool_name ?>">
            <svg viewbox="0 0 50 50">
              <?php echo $tool_image;
              echo file_get_contents($tool_image); ?>
            </svg>
            <img src="http://www.mantasmilka.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/photoshop.svg" alt="" />
            <?php get_template_part(images/inline, 'http://www.mantasmilka.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/photoshop.svg.php'); ?>
          </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried numerous solutions and nothing seems to work... Does anybody have any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: If it works locally but not on your server than the problem may not be in your code but may be due to a difference in server configurations.  For example, your server may be blocking the file name "photoshop.svg.php" while your local system is letting it through.

Comment: The thing is, if i wrap it i img tag it works on the server side. I've added to svg .php extension so the including of svgs would work through get_tenplate_part()  as suggested in this tutorial. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/perfect-wordpress-inline-svg-workflow sadly this one does not even work on localhost. Anyway, uploading svgs to wp-admin works with plugin for svg support no problem, but getting the contents and pasting them inline - not really.

Comment: Maybe your server isn't serving SVG as an image, this happened to me once... Read [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/serve-svg-image)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look in this tomorrow. Big thanks for any of your input!

Answer (score 0):

Not really answer your exact question, but this is one of few question that pops up on Google search "svg works locally but not on server". Hope it help future researchers.

In my case the reason was simple to understand and fix.

Locally I was working on a file directly, but on remote that file was included. So locally I had `file.php` and `image.svg` in "root" and I called it with

```html
<img alt="..." title="..." src="image.svg">
```

which worked great.

When on server the file structure was something like

```
[root]
+-[includes]
| +-[MY_INCLUDE_FOLDER]
|   +-image.svg
|   +-file.php
+-index.php
```

and somewhere in `index.php` there was this line

```php
include_once __DIR__ . '/includes/MY_INCLUDE_FOLDER/file.php';
```

Now since this was not just a simple call to PHP script, with PHP output, but an entire webpage with HTML, it also had a line `<base href="https://example.com/">`.

This means that `<img>` source was actually `https://example.com/image.svg` instead of `https://example.com/includes/MY_INCLUDE_FOLDER/image.svg`.